# OSMDroid Bonus Pack - gradle.build error - Failed to Resolve Dependency

Tags: java, android, android-studio, osmdroid

I'm attempting to follow the [HowToInclude](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/HowToInclude) tutorial, however I've run into an issue with the dependency failing to resolve. Specifically, this step:

> Then in the build.gradle of your app, add this dependency:
>
> dependencies {
>       ...
>     compile 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.5.1'
>   }
>   and that's it.

Upon trying to sync Gradle I get the following error:

> Failed to Resolve: com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.5.1

Comment: I experience the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41529064/5093897). Hopefully osmbonuspack documentation will be improved.