# jitpack not finding new versions of github repo but can find old ones

Tags: java, gradle, jitpack

I have the following `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: "java"

version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src"]

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies{
    compileOnly 'com.github.Recessive:repo:v0.5' 
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.12'
}

jar{
    archiveFileName = "${project.archivesBaseName}.jar"
    from{
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect{it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    }

    from(rootDir){
        include "plugin.json"
    }
}
```

That isn't working and returning the error

```
LocalRepo1:main: Could not find com.github.Recessive.repo:v0.5:.
```

To add salt to the wound, I released a `v0.2` three months ago, and this works perfectly fine. Changing the line

`compileOnly 'com.github.Recessive:repo:v0.5'`

to

`compileOnly 'com.github.Recessive:repo:v0.2'`

will build with the older version no problem. I've released `v0.3` to `v0.5` as troubleshooting just to try and get jitpack to work, they are all functionally the same. I tried using the `master-SNAPSHOT` as well but this stopped working when I made the `v0.3` release for unknown reasons.

The only error I will get regardless of the issue is the one stated before, making it basically impossible to know what is going on without significant knowledge of jitpack and gradle, hence the question here.

If anyone has any idea why this error might have suddenly popped up help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: Also I know jitpack is returning the `v0.2` version properly as I checked the link manually. While gradle is just building from the cached version jitpack is also behaving as expected

Answer (score 0):

90% sure this was caused by the git history being too long (ie, over 500mb). To fix this I did the following:

```
git checkout --orphan <orphan-branch-name>
git commit

git push <remote-name> <orphan-branch-name>
```

This created an orphan branch with no commit history. Then in the build file I replaced the version with:

```
dependencies{
    compileOnly "com.github.Recessive:repo:orphan-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

And it started working. Gradle/Jitpack has a horrendous lack of proper error reporting, as is evident but the [most common error message from Jitpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058358/jitpack-io-failed-to-resolve-github-repo) having *10 different answers*