# Gradle and adding github projects as dependencies, some clarifications

Tags: java, android, github, gradle, netbeans-8

I am pretty new to Gradle, I followed some tutorials and read around wikis and guides but I still have some questions I couldn't clearly find an answer for.

What I'd like to have are some clarifications about Gradle and general github project dependencies.

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798694/add-github-library-as-dependency-to-android-studio-project), he mentions the following example:

```
dependencies {  
    mavenCentral()
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+'
}
```

I get `com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh`, it is basically `com.github.username.repository`, but what do exactly represent `extra-abc` and the `+`?

On the gradle irc they said the first one is the artifact and they gave me [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html), where it says: `Dependency configurations are also used to publish files`.. but I still don't get.. which files and for which purpouse you want to do that? I guess artifacts should refer to jars, but why giving it a name (`extra-abc`)?

`+` takes the place where the version usually is, so I assume it should indicate the latest version, shouldn't it?

Moreover, is the example I pasted valid for both gradle and plain (netbeans) projects hosted on github or do we have to differentiate?

I am using Netbeans 8.02 with the gradle plugin.

Sorry for the dumb questions, but I really want to clear my doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [this library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) is **NO LONGER BEING MAINTAINED**. You should use the support library.

> I get com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh, it is basically com.github.username.repository,

It is not correct.
This library is published on Maven Central.

The `com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh` is the **groupId** of the artifact that you can find on Maven.

> but what do exactly represent extra-abc

The `extra-abc` is the **name of the artifact** (the name of the library...) on Maven.

Here you can find [the full list](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh).

```
|GroupId                                     |ArtifactId|   Latest Version|
|--------------------------------------------|----------|-----------------|
|com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh|library   |            0.9.9|
|com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh|extra-abs |            0.9.9|
|com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh|extra-abc |            0.9.9|
```

> and the +

It indicates to gradle to use the last version. 
In your case you can use one of these:

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:0.+'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:0.9.+'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:0.9.9'
```

Pay attention, the use of `+` is not in general a good idea, because you can't know what version you are using.
In this case, since the library is deprecated it is not a problem.

**EDIT**
If the question is **how can I add a github project that is not present on the maven repo as a reference to my project then?**

Pls refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053779/create-a-gradle-dependency-to-import-from-git/33053965#33053965):

Comment: The `actionbarpulltorefresh` was just an example but thanks for the explanation and the suggestion about the `+`. Anyway, how can I add a github project that is not present on the maven repo as a reference to my project then?

Comment: @elect In this case you can follow this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053779/create-a-gradle-dependency-to-import-from-git/33053965#33053965