# Access remote gradle dependency

Tags: android, git, maven, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This is my first time to make remote repository. But I am facing some problem in accessing it. Following are my gradle files:

**root gradle file**

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
 common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle file**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.imagelettericon"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.github.akashandroid90:imageletter:1.0'
}
```

and each time when I sync the code I am getting same error

> Failed to resolve: `com.github.akashandroid90:imageletter:1.0`

I have follow [this](http://brianattwell.com/distributing-android-libs-via-jcenter/) and [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) link to make my repo. But now I am not able to access it in gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo have to change your dependency.
`compile 'com.github.akashandroid90:imageletter:1.0'`  is wrong.

Reading the doc in the github repo you should use.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.imageletter:ImageLetterIcon:1.0'
}
```

However you can check the dependency in the [jcenter repo](https://bintray.com/akashandroid90/maven/image-letter-icon/view).
Reading the pom file in the repo, I have some doubs about the name.
**It should be:**

```
compile 'com.github.akashandroid90:image-letter-icon:1.0'
```

You can use another way to add a dependency with a github project,using the github repo and the [**jitpack** plugin](https://jitpack.io/)
In this case you have to add this repo tp your `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

and the dependency:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
    }
```

In your case it is

```
compile 'com.github.akashandroid90:ImageLetterIcon:1.0'
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053779/create-a-gradle-dependency-to-import-from-git/33053965#33053965).

Comment: I had also tried again and again
compile 'com.github.akashandroid90:image-letter-icon:1.0'

But i am still getting same error.

Comment: I have also tried with jitpack using compile 'com.github.akashandroid90:ImageLetterIcon:v1.0'  as show on jitpack

But getting same error

Comment: @AkashJain 'com.github.akashandroid90:ImageLetterIcon:v1.0' does work so most likely jitpack repository is missing from build.gradle or its in the wrong place. People sometimes place it under buildscript by mistake.

Comment: I had made the same mistake i had put lib in buildscript. So I have made changes but again I am not able to use it using jitpack

Comment: I have also make repo on maven and jcenter but not able to access them also in gradle

Comment: @AkashJain some proxy to config?

Comment: No I haven't make any proxy setting. And I have also update my repository on maven. but i am still not able to get it.

Comment: I got my solution.Thanx