# I want to create my own gradle dependecy

Tags: android, github, gradle, dependencies, repository

I have a github repository and I want to make it as a gradle dependency so that anyone can add in his build gradle.

can anyone help me?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a gradle dependency to import from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053779/create-a-gradle-dependency-to-import-from-git)

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload it to **jcenter** or **Maven Central**

you can read how to do so [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en)

---

or the easiest way you can just use [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/)

as noted in the comments this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33053965/3998402

Answer (score 0):

I personally thing that [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) is a hack and shouldn't be used in the real world.

The simplest option is to sign up to bintray and use the [bintray gradle plugin](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin) to deploy your artifacts there.

You can also deploy to [maven central](https://search.maven.org/) which can be more difficult than bintray. For instance maven central requires that you "own" the domain for your group id (many people use their github domain as their group id). Maven central also requires much more info including authors and other fields.

You can also [host a maven repo on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github) which I've done myself [here](https://github.com/uklance/releases). This relies on the `https://raw.github.com` URL structure to serve up the jars as binary.